# Speeding up JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that runs to check the amount of times certain options are selected in dropdowns. The page has about a thousand or more dropdowns. When selecting a dropdown, after clicking the option you want, we get about a 5 second freeze before it selects and updates values. when removing the JavaScript it runs instantly and OK. Is there a way to speed up how the JavaScript runs?

This is the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getSelectedValues(){
        var matches1 = $('#group1 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '1';
        }).length;
        var matches2 = $('#group2 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '2';
        }).length;
        var matches3 = $('#group3 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '3';
        }).length;
            var matches4 = $('#group4 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '4';
        }).length;
            var matches5 = $('#group5 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '5';
        }).length;
            var matches6 = $('#group6 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '6';
        }).length;
            var matches7 = $('#group7 select').filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == '7';
        }).length;

        // here's where we just update that new <span>
        if(matches1 > 1 || matches2 > 1 || matches3 > 1 || matches4 > 1 || matches5 > 1 || matches6 > 1 || matches7 > 1){
            $('span#resultgroup1<%=pempidw2%>').css( "color", "red" );
        }
        if(matches1 < 2 && matches2 < 2 && matches3 < 2 && matches4 < 2 && matches5 < 2 && matches6 < 2 && matches7 < 2){
            $('span#resultgroup1<%=pempidw2%>').css( "color", "black" );
        }  
    }

    // and here we bind to the change event for the selects
    // and re-call our above function.
    $('select').on('change', getSelectedValues);


</script>
```

It is JavaScript to help avoid the user entering the same answer in more than one section. It all works 100% just slow.

Comment: You have this question tagged as Java, but I don't see any Java here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you store the data and simply update it with a change handler instead of massive DOM search each time?

Comment: ...the page has a thousand drop downs?

Comment: Is there a way to speed up how the JavaScript runs? No. Can you write code that runs faster? Yes.

Comment: Some of your inefficiencies are going to come from all the DOM querying you do in the event handler. Assuming you want to act on the same dropdowns each time the handler is run, cache the `$('#groupX select')` queries (and other queries) before setting up the handler, and then use them via closure in the handler function.

Comment: Honestly, if your page has a thousand dropdowns, you should probably rethink the whole deisgn (in addition to the other suggestions of how to improve the JavaScript).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it is large data entry for a lot of things used once/week.

Comment: @Jonathan do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @antt Yes, rewrite the whole thing in Angular

Comment: Ignore the people who are telling you to rewrite it, these same people told me that I couldn't put 3000 checkboxes on a form and it worked fine when I ironed out the bugs.

Comment: There's a huge difference between "can't" and "shouldn't". This code, while working, is a great example of code that could be improved by following good coding practices. Sometimes the answer to how to improve something is genuinely to [throw away the prototype](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-prototype-pitfall/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're taking full advantage of javascript/jquery language!
(aka you can speed up how your code runs, but not javascript itself)

Theres a lot of copy/pasted code e.g.

```
var matches7 = $('#group7 select').filter(function(){
return $(this).val() == '7';
```

These vars all be refactored in to one method call passing in the different class variables to save on space and help speed up the program a little.  Once your refactor them you can just do:

```
if $(this).val(){$(this).parent().css{ *set whatever css here}}
```

That'll be a major speed up since you don't have to check all values after for every type, just the class your variable your ($this) is.

Edit: I realized that the .filters() can wreak havoc on the DOM, try using `$("select[value=1]:checked").length` instead for better overall performance

Hope that helps!